# Sessions showing null error

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have a JSP page, say xyz.jsp in which I've set a session

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("path", loc);
```

and in a.java I've used this session successfully and sent response back to jsp page,

```
String fpath = request.getSession().getAttribute("path").toString();
```

But, when I to use the same session value in b.java I am getting null pointer exception.

my.jsp->on button click->a.java->get session1->send response to my.jsp->my.jsp reloads->b.java trying to use session1->NullPointerExceptionError

I've tried,

1. Using different session variables

   ```
   session.setAttribute("session1", loc);
   session.setAttribute("session2", loc);
   ```
2. Creating a new session variable in a.java and access the same in b.java

Still with the same error.

my.jsp looks like,

```
String loc = "/u/poolla/workspace/FirstServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/" + ip +"/" +timeStamp;
session.setAttribute("path", loc);
```

a.java looks like

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String fpath = session.getAttribute("path").toString();


    if(!new File(fpath).exists())
    {
        File uploadedFile = new File(fpath, fileName);
                    item.write(uploadedFile);
        two_file = "Right file " +fileName;
            request.setAttribute("file2", two_file);
        String f2 = "<span class='blue'>" +"Uploaded file " +fileName+ " at " +uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath()+ "<br>" + "</span>";
                    request.setAttribute("f2stat", f2);
    }

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("geco.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

b.java looks like

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String b = session.getAttribute("path").toString();
            File file = new File(b);
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("hi");
            bw.close();
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more code?

Comment: Of which part do you want?

Comment: Show us your servlet code?

Comment: is your String fpath having the correct value? i mean are you setting session attribute correctly. why not request.getSession().setAttribute("session1", loc);

Comment: If you are getting Null ptr exception when invoking session.getAttribute, then it means your session is destroyed in the current page. can you check that

Comment: Yes, the string fpath has a correct value assignment as I am able to access the same in a.java

Comment: Does the session actually have the attribute you're trying to retrieve? If that hasn't been set, getAttribute() will return null.

Comment: Yes, it does have a value which I am able to access in a.java but when I try to access the same in b.java it fails. Updated code. pl check.

Comment: @VigneshVino Updated code. Pl check.

Comment: @prash I've done that, I guess they are all the same right?

Comment: one is session being null, other is attribute being not set..anyway that's not the problm here

Comment: Yes, either way they do the same job. I'm still not able to figure it out where it's going wrong

Comment: I will share the code what i tried. Basically it should work, You can compare with mine and let me know if you have some change in the way to handle session

Comment: Okay, I'll do it and update you. Will you paste it here as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just to help you with the problem. What i mean to say is using the scriptlets in jsp, the naming conventions, using two servlets in this scenario are all not recommended..

code snippets

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservleta</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.examples.example.MyServletA</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservletb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.examples.example.MyServletB</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservleta</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservletb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.go</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<body>
    <%
        session.setAttribute("location", "tvm");
    %>
    <form action="gotoajava.do" method="post">
        <input type="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**page2.jsp**

```
<body>
    <form action="gotobjava.go" method="get">
        <input type="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**MyServletA.java**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String loc = request.getSession().getAttribute("location").toString();
        System.out.println("location in ServletA from session is " + loc);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("geco.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
```

**MyServletB.java**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String loc = session.getAttribute("location").toString();
        System.out.println("location in ServletB from session is " + loc);

    }
```

**Console log:**

```
Mar 20, 2014 9:28:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 343 ms
location in ServletA from session is tvm
location in ServletB from session is tvm
```

*edit: The jsp that performs 'gotobjava.go' action is renamed to page2.jsp as per OP's edit request*

Comment: I did everything the same bro, still the null pointer persists.

Comment: ok did you follow my code or you tried this a reference?, you also mentioned my.jsp->on button click->a.java->get session1->send response to my.jsp->my.jsp reloads->b.java trying to use session1->NullPointerExceptionError . Can you show me how you implemented this? "my.jsp reloads->b.java" ?

Comment: Yes, I did..But I can't actually stitch that into my servlet as a lot of things are inter-dependednt and all I want to do is to be able to pass sessions to multiple receivers. Anyways, thanks for your code, I'll re-check things and try to edit my code based on your approach.

Comment: Hey I guess I did a mistake somewhere, I'm checking with it. Might take longer. I'll leave feed back once I am done.